# mongoDB : find list in list with any order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to do a find request in `mongoDB` with the condition:
"if element contains a list that contains exactly theses elements".
It makes more sense with an example:

```
{
"categories" : [ 
        [ 
            "dogs", 
            "cats"
        ], 
        [ 
            "dogs", 
            "octopus"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I want to find an element with a category containing only "dogs" and "octopus".

`find({ 'categories' : ['dogs','octopus']})` finds the element

`find({ 'categories' : ['octopus','dogs']})` doesn't find and that's where my issue is since I don't care about the order in the list

The output would be all the elements with a category containing only "dogs" and "octopus"

I am not sure if it's possible but if it's not the two solutions I see would be to store them in alphabetic order (good but what if I need the order afterwards?) or to store/search all the possible orders (very ugly)

Comment: Just to note that MongoDB doesn't care if the data value is a Array or a single value, when the query is run it will check the key and if it's a string it will try match it if it's an array it will search through the array values for a match.

Comment: What is the expected result of your query? do you need all others sub-array in your `categories` field?

Comment: The result would be all the elements with a category containing only "dogs" and "octopus".

Comment: @Bajo please check if my answer gives you the expected output. and leave comment if not satisfied. also you can edit your post to add the expected output

Comment: Can't you `$or` the two queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**aggregation pipelines**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/)

```js
 db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$categories" }, 
    { "$match": { "categories" : { "$all" : [ "dogs", "octopus" ]}}}
])
```

This gives you the following document

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c6685e7cdaa3f3e4dd8def"),
    "categories" : [ "dogs", "octopus" ] 
}
```